# Retain controls and properties generated in SelectedIndexChanged

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi first time posting here so sorry if I am a bit ambiguous.

So I am building an ASP.NET web app and I am using a DropDownList to generate a CheckBoxList for the user to check. After they have checked the boxes they wish to they will press a button that will execute a function based on what checkboxes were checked.

My issue comes in when the page posts back after the button press, meaning that the  selection criteria on the checkboxes are lost because I am regenerating the CheckBoxList on the button press.

I have my click event hitting the SelectedIndexChanged event and setting the selected index on the DropDownList so it retains the selected index/value and generates the CheckBoxList again, but how would I go about retaining the state of the checkboxes?

Again, sorry if it is a bit ambiguous or just a silly question overall.
Thanks!

Edit:

The following is a basic representation of my code and what I'm trying to do:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        //Populate dropdown
    }
}

protected void Dropdown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(drpDownList.SelectedIndex > 0)
    {
        string strValue = drpDownList.Value;

        CheckBoxList chkBoxList = new CheckBoxList();

        //Query database for information based on dropdownlist value
        chkBoxList.Items.Add(new ListItem() { Text = strValue, Value = "" /* what was queried */ });
    }
}

protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control ctlControl in pnlPanel.Controls)
    {
        if (ctlControl is CheckBoxList)
        {
            CheckBoxList chkBoxList = (CheckBoxList)ctlControl;

            foreach (ListItem lisItem in chkBoxList.Items)
            {
                if (lisItem.Selected == true)
                {
                    //Do whatever
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The issue lies in after you select a dropdownlist index, the page generates a checkboxlist for user interaction. Once they are done and click the button to check the properties of the checkboxlist, it fails to as the checkboxlist is dependant on the SelectedIndexChanged method, meaning that any decisions the user made will be wiped and the code will not execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out how to solve my problem, though I had to resort to javascript. I just made a javascript function to loop through the generated checkboxes by giving the generated list a static ID to reference. I then built a string up that had the checkbox values, then passed it to a hidden control and referenced that in the button click on the codebehind.

The function made references the first solution on the following page:
https://forums.asp.net/t/1335376.aspx?Loop+through+checkboxlist+with+Javascript

The function is as follows:

```
        function ReadCheckboxes() {
            var varList = document.getElementById('CONTROLID').getElementsByTagName("input");

            if (eval(varList)) {
                var varCollatString = '';

                for (var i = 0; i < varList.length; i++) {
                    if (varList[i].checked == true) {
                        var varID = varList[i].value + ',';
                        varCollatString += varID;                        
                    }
                }

                var varHidden = document.getElementById('HIDDENCONTROL');
                varHidden.value = varCollatString;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

- You have a server side DropDownList to generate a CheckBoxList
- You have a server button to collect selected items

Solution :

- You need to use `!IsPostBack` condition to bind dropdownlist
- Don't use SelectedIndexChanged event, because you have already a button to collected selected items
- On button click event apply for loop to get selected items

Try this :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        //Bind your drop downlist here
    }
}



protected void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for(int x=0;x<ddl1.Items.Count;x++)
    {
        if(ddl1.Items[x].Selected)
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have my DropDownList being populated in the page load within an if(!IsPostBack) statement, so that works, but I'm still having problems with the CheckBoxList. I need to use the SelectedIndexChanged event as it generates a CheckBoxList on the page relevant to the list selection, so each time you pick a DropDownList item the page will refresh and draw the new CheckBoxList.

For example, click list index, generate new checkboxlist, allow user to check as they please, click button, execute processing. The problem being that the checkboxlist doesn't remember the selections and just regenerates.

Comment: @Jason, give your code file (Aspx and Aspx.cs) to get more idea.

Comment: Hi sorry for the late response, I have added a basic representation of what I am trying to do in the question section. Thanks!